# Prove the locus of intersection of 2 circles on 2 sides of triangle as chords is hyperbola.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections, locus

## Question

Prove that the locus of the intersection of two equal circles which are described on two sides $EF$ and $EG$ of a triangle as chords is a rectangular hyperbola whose center is the midpoint of $FG$ and which passes through $E$,$F$ and $G$.

## Attempt

Consider a triangle $EFG$ with $E(x_1,y_1)$,$F(x_2,y_2)$,$G(x_3,y_3)$ as vertices.
Consider two equal circles,
$$S_1:=x^2+y^2+2g_1x+2f_1y+c_1=0$$
$$S_2:=x^2+y^2+2g_2x+2f_2y+c_2=0$$
Therefore, the condition of equal radii $(r_1=r_2)$ gives,
$$\sqrt {g_1^2+f_1^2-c_1^2}=\sqrt {g_2^2+f_2^2-c_2^2}$$
As $EF$ is the chord of $S_1$,
$$x_1^2+y_1^2+2g_1x_1+2f_1y_1+c_1=0$$
$$x_2^2+y_2^2+2g_1x_2+2f_1y_2+c_1=0$$
As $EG$ is the chord of $S_2$,
$$x_1^2+y_1^2+2g_2x_1+2f_2y_1+c_2=0$$
$$x_3^2+y_3^2+2g_2x_3+2f_2y_3+c_2=0$$
Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ meet in $(h,k)$. Then we have,
$$h^2+k^2+2g_1h+2f_1k+c_1=0$$
$$h^2+k^2+2g_2h+2f_2k+c_2=0$$
What now I have to do is prove that $(h-\frac {x_2+x_3}{2})^2 - (k-\frac {y_2+y_3}{2})^2=A^2$ for some constant $A$. One value of $(h,k)$ is clearly $(x_1,y_1)$. Yet neither I can derive the other value of $(h,k)$ nor prove the desired result, for it looks tremendously tedious. Can anyone help me to make the way out?

## Edit

Playing with the slope of the common chord of the circles, I find another linear equation in $h$ and $k$,
$$h(f_1-f_2)+k(g_1-g_2)=x_1(f_1-f_2)+y_1(g_1-g_2)$$
As the resulting hyperbola passes through $E$,$F$ and $G$, I have another set of results,
$$(x_1-\frac {x_2+x_3}{2})^2 - (y_1-\frac {y_2+y_3}{2})^2=A^2$$
$$(x_2-\frac {x_2+x_3}{2})^2 - (y_2-\frac {y_2+y_3}{2})^2=A^2$$
$$(x_3-\frac {x_2+x_3}{2})^2 - (y_3-\frac {y_2+y_3}{2})^2=A^2$$
Moreover , as suggested in the comment, I would add that this is the case of a conic through 5 points, $E,F,G,$ the reflections of $E$ in the circumcentre of $∆EFG$ and in the midpoint of $FG$.

Comment: I believe this is the $5$-point conic through $E$, $F$, $G$, the reflection of $E$ in the circumcenter of $\triangle EFG$, and the reflection of $E$ in the midpoint of $\overline{FG}$. The center is the midpoint of $\overline{FG}$. I got this through some ugly coordinate-bashing in *Mathematica*. I'm seeking a cleaner derivation, along with a showing that the resulting hyperbola is rectangular.

Comment: @Blue, have you tried parametric forms , I suspect if they can be of a use.